# SED: Strange behavior in sh and bash, ok in zsh

Tags: bash, sed, sh, zsh

I have a strange behavior with a `sed` command.

First, my concern is to have a `sed` command in a Bash script that enables me to replace a string located after the string `sas_token`.

Here is the file:

```
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=2023-11-21T09%3A51Z&sp=rwl&sip=94.233.160.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=9G5tqn7RZxagUgnvpenBGm%2BNQVipRYOFxjz6l6mrvtg%3D"
```

I then generate a new token that I want to replace in the file above.
I want to use `sed`.
As my generated token contains ampersand (`&`), I must use substring replacement like this:

```
${NEW_TOKEN//&/\\&}
```

That's giving us this `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/\(^sas_token =\)\(\s*.*$\)/\1 "'${NEW_TOKEN//&/\\&}'"/' .ENV/app-backend.tfvars
```

But it's not working in `bash` or `sh` environment, only in `zsh`. But the goal is to achieve this in `bash` only.

Please find below full explanation:

#### Testing with `bash`:

Checking  interpreter:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform$ ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep
minime 15853    3349  0 11:23 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
minime 16045   15853  0 11:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Checking file before modifying:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform$ less -F .ENV/app-backend.tfvars
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=2023-11-21T09%3A51Z&sp=rwl&sip=94.233.160.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=9G5tqn7RZxagUgnvpenBGm%2BNQVipRYOFxjz6l6mrvtg%3D"
```

Checking new string to replace `sas_token` line:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform$ echo ${TEST_STRING}
se=1998-11-21T08%3A49Z&sp=rwl&sip=193.253.170.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DE7xk1ggg%3D
```

Running `sed`:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~//terraform$ sed 's/\(^sas_token =\)\(\s*.*$\)/\1 "'${TEST_STRING//&/\\&}'"/' .ENV/app-backend.tfvars
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=2023-11-21T09%3A51Z&sp=rwl&sip=94.233.160.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=9G5tqn7RZxagUgnvpenBGm%2BNQVipRYOFxjz6l6mrvtg%3D"
```

See? The `sas_token` value **did not change**...

#### Testing with `zsh`:

Checking  interpreter:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform  ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep
mini-me    3349    3329  0 09:20 pts/2    00:00:02 /usr/bin/zsh -i
mini-me   16618    3349  0 11:42 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Checking file before modifying:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform  less -F .ENV/app-backend.tfvars
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=2023-11-21T09%3A51Z&sp=rwl&sip=94.233.160.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=9G5tqn7RZxagUgnvpenBGm%2BNQVipRYOFxjz6l6mrvtg%3D"
```

Checking new string to replace `sas_token` line:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform  echo ${TEST_STRING}
se=1998-11-21T08%3A49Z&sp=rwl&sip=193.253.170.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DE7xk1ggg%3D
```

Running `sed`:

```
minime@yd-202203101028:~/terraform  sed 's/\(^sas_token =\)\(\s*.*$\)/\1 "'${TEST_STRING//&/\\&}'"/' .ENV/app-backend.tfvars
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=1998-11-21T08%3A49Z&sp=rwl&sip=193.253.170.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DE7xk1ggg%3D"%
```

See? The `sas_token value` **HAD changed**!

What am I missing in `bash` (or `sh`)?

Comment: `$NEW_TOKEN` is outside of any quoting. In bash, the variable is first expanded and the result then word-splitted. In zsh, the whole command is first word-splitted, and then the parameter is expanded. You can't expect identical behaviour of bash and zsh. Decide first, which language you are using, and then write the program. It does not make sense to write a program and run it as two different languages.

Comment: @user1934428: You're true, I forgot to mention that my target language is bash!

Comment: @user1934428: What do you mean by `outside of any quoting`?

Comment: So your question boils down to _Why does my sed command not work as expected_? In this case, you post too much irrelevant code. You could reduce your example to doing a simple `TEST_STRING=.... ; echo "your token line" | sed YOUR_SED_PARAMETERS` and show what output you get, and describe what output you expect instead.

Comment: BTW, at a first glance, I see that your sed pattern is using \s to match after the equal sign, while your file has a space here. From this I would conclude that  the pattern does not match.

Comment: Outside of quoting: The variable $TEST_STRING is neither between single quotes nor between double quotes. If there would be a space in the variable, word splitting would occur. I would put it between double quotes.

Comment: @user1934428: Maybe you think I put too much info, but others could want to think more globally than you!
`your sed pattern is using \s to match after the equal sign`. Yes, indeed, I want to match a space? What's the matter?

Comment: @user1934428: I think you're wrong when you say `Outside of quoting: The variable $TEST_STRING is neither between single quotes nor between double quotes.`. In the sed command the variables is firt between simple quotes, then alos between double quoits (because I need it beoing double quoted in the final file).

Comment: You have an opening single quotes before the initial `s/`. It's closing quote is just before the `$`. BTW, it's fortunate that the variable is not between single quotes; if it were, it would not be expanded.

Comment: As for \s, I don't think it matches a space. Of course it could depend on the `sed` version, which you did not specify. I suggest that you double check the man-page for the valid regex characters.

Comment: If it works in Zsh, it's probably supported by their `sed` version.

Comment: Works for me in Bash with double quotes added around `${TEST_STRING//blah/blah}`: https://ideone.com/xxuCt9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I was going to say, just try `...."'"${NEW_TOKEN//&/\\&}"'"....` (-; Note the extra dbl-quotes just before and after the `${var}` wrapper chars. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, `\s` is a nonportable extension that originated in PCRE -- `sed`, which is documented only to support BRE or ERE syntax, isn't guaranteed to support it. The more reliable way to match whitespace is `[[:space:]]`

Comment: In this case though, the OP is using GNU sed (can tell by how they're using `-i` without a subsequent backup file name), and GNU sed does support `\s` as meaning white space.

Comment: _nod_, good point to make that `-i` is a nonportable extension too.

Comment: @Greg'ory, ...to demonstrate how the shells you're testing with differ, btw, think about running `printf '%s\n\n' sed 's/\(^sas_token =\)\(\s*.*$\)/\1 "'${TEST_STRING//&/\\&}'"/' .ENV/app-backend.tfvars` in each of bash and zsh and comparing the results. You'll see that zsh breaks the POSIX standard (in a place where it's arguably reasonable, in hindsight decades later, to decide the standard encodes a bad decision) by declining to word-split on unquoted whitespace; whereas bash follows the standard and splits into two arguments the way any compliant shell is required to do.

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem you're seeing is due to your quoting. You need (surrounding spaces and quoted strings underneath added for emphasis):

```
sed 's/foo/"'  "$bar"  '"/'
    '<----->'  "<-->"  '<>'
```

instead of:

```
sed 's/foo/"'   $bar   '"/'
    '<----->'          '<>'
```

as the latter leaves `$bar` unquoted and so exposed to the shell for interpretation and then it's up to the shell you're running in and whatever environment variables have been set in it to decide what to do with that.

You already identified one additional issue, that `&` needs to be escaped, but it's not just `&`s that would need escaping, other characters would too even just in the backreference (`\`, `/`, etc.), see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

The fundamental problem is that sed doesn't understand literal strings, but awk does so just use awk instead of trying to escape all the metachars to make sed behave as if they were literal:

```
$ new='se=1998-11-21T08%3A49Z&sp=rwl&sip=193.253.170.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DE7xk1ggg%3D' \
    awk '$1=="sas_token" { $3="\"" ENVIRON["new"] "\"" } 1' file
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "se=1998-11-21T08%3A49Z&sp=rwl&sip=193.253.170.130&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=DE7xk1ggg%3D"
```

```
$ new='~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`|}{[]\":'\'';?></.,' \
    awk '$1=="sas_token" { $3="\"" ENVIRON["new"] "\"" } 1' file
storage_account_name = "stoftfstate"
container_name = "tfstate-ct"
key = "terraform.tfstate"
sas_token = "~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`|}{[]\":';?></.,"
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for why I'm specifying the shell variable value on the same line as the awk script and using `ENVIRON[]` (plus alternatives).